# Comandos personalizados

Tags: python, discord.py

me gustaria saber si existe alguna manera de que por medio de un comando, se agregen otros, algo asi:

```
!addcommand Hola {user.mention} hola.
```

Y luego cuando ponga !Hola salga lo que puse a un lado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera mas fácil de agregar comandos a tu bot es:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

"resto del código"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
@bot.command(0
async def tu_comando():
  "código"
```

Comment: ah, gracias, ya lo habia solucionado